# Problems with phing fileset excludes

Tags: phing

I am having trouble with excludes in a phing fileset. I have the following task

```
<target name="package" depends="exportsources">
    <if>
        <available file="${exports_dir}" type="dir" />
        <then>
            <tar destfile="${application.startdir}/../package.tar">
                <fileset dir="${exports_dir}">
                    <exclude name="application/cache/" />
                    <exclude name="application/config/" />
                    <exclude name="application/logs/" />
                    <exclude name="build/" />
                    <exclude name="nbproject/" />
                    <exclude name="uploads/" />
                    <exclude name="index.php" />
                    <exclude name="sqlupdates" />
                </fileset>
            </tar>
        </then>
        <else>
            <fail message="Nothing to package!" />
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

The tar task is properly excluding the directories of `build/`, `exclude/`, and `uploads/` as well as the file `index.php`.

The three *directories* under `application/` (`cache`, `config`, and `logs`), however, are not being excluded, and neither is the *file* `sqlupdates`.

Does anyone have any tips for me, please?

Comment: Phing does not seem to like subfolders. Try leaving just `<exclude name="logs/" />` - worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Wow, I am surprised by this--especially given the combination with something like `tar`. The problem with simply using `name="logs/"` is that it is not selective enough. I may have another logs directory elsewhere which I do not want to exclude. Oh well. Thanks again!